# How to make my PC become an "psudo/fake" external display for Android phone via USB ports (without using any USB to HDMI dongles)

Tags: windows, android, linux, usb

I want my Android phone to recognize my PC as its external display (psuedo/fake or virtual displays) via USB connection (USB-C - USB-A cable or TCP connection) without using any USB to HDMI dongles or WiFi display like Miracast either.

I think I need to find or write the app/software or driver on PC side which have USB protocol like any real USB-C to HDMI display to communicate with the phone. Do you have any suggestion or guidelines?

Thanks

Comment: If you just want to mirror your screen to your PC, maybe take a look at my list of [ADB Programs for your computer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb#group_947). Some of them even allow you to control your device that way via mouse and keyboard on your PC. And as there's a thing like "wireless ADB", you would need the USB cable only once to enable the connection from your PC (or not even that if your device is rooted).

Comment: Reposted on [Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1799055/356789) and [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/87533/520)

Comment: you could try the cast feature in android

Answer (score 1):

[scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) should work. Bonus is you can control your phone from your PC. From the project README:

> This application mirrors Android devices (video and audio) connected via USB or over TCP/IP, and allows to control the device with the keyboard and the mouse of the computer. It does not require any root access. It works on Linux, Windows and macOS.

Comment: Great app, was unaware of this